# VK_FORMAT_R16_UINT texture format in Vulkan

Tags: textures, vulkan

Vulkan does not have any pixel transfer functionality like OpenGL does. But how does the `VK_FORMAT_R16_UINT` format works? Can use it to sample unsigned short value from the pixel shader? When I use it, I only get zeros from the sampler. I am using linear filtering.

If I use the format `VK_FORMAT_R16_UNORM` instead of `VK_FORMAT_R16_UINT` I get values between `0-1` so I guess Vulkan normalize the values for me in that case?

Comment: Are you using linear filtering? Support for that is not guaranteed for VK_FORMAT_R16_UNORM. Have you checked you have no validation errors?

Comment: @Columbo yes I am using linear filtering and I have no validation errors.

Comment: To use linear filtering on VK_FORMAT_R16_UINT you need to first check for support using vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties (check for VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_SAMPLED_IMAGE_FILTER_LINEAR_BIT). Can you verify if it's supported?

Comment: @Columbo It did not support it, I thought the validation layer would tell me something if it was not supported, thank you. Can you write your comment in an answer so I can put it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for linear filtering for the format `VK_FORMAT_R16_UINT` is not guaranteed by the spec.

Before using linear filtering on `VK_FORMAT_R16_UINT` you need to first check for support using `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties` (check for `VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_SAMPLED_IMAGE_FILTER_LINEAR_BIT`).

It is surprising that the validation layers did not report the misuse. It would be worth filing an enhancement request to get that check added.

Comment: I've opened an issue to get this check added.